# Use a global variable from js file in html code

Tags: javascript, html

I have got a file called report.js which has a variable called "number". I would like to show this number in the html page.

report.js is as below:

```
var number;

module exports:{}

    getData:function(data){
    //calculate number

}
```

and the index.html is as below:
...

```
<body>
<div class="page">
    <header style="position: relative;">
        <h1 style="margin-left: 140px;" id="newNumber"></h1> 
    </header>


<script>
    $("#newNumber").html('<div align="left">Number is '+ number +'</div>');
</script>

</body>
```

should I add this line? and where?

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='js/report.js'></script>
```

Comment: You cannot use module exports in client side javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add that line in the header.  It will go in the same place as your document title.

`<head>
        <script type='text/javascript' src='js/report.js'></script>
    </head>`